# Turn a decision problem into a linear filter problem

Tags: filters, filter-design, linear-systems, linear-prediction

Let $x[n]$ be a time-series, and two filters:

- $A[n] = a_0 x[n] + a_1 x[n-1] + ... a_q x[n-q]$
- $B[n] = b_0 x[n] + b_1 x[n-1] + ... b_r x[n-r]$

I think the answer is No, but is there a way to have this problem (sign of 2 filters should be both positive):

$$A[n] > 0 \quad AND \quad  B[n] > 0$$

expressed in terms of the study of the sign of a **single linear filter**

$$C[n] = c_0 x[n] + c_1 x[n-1] + ... c_s x[n-s]$$

?

If not possible, is there a way to have nearly equivalence (that holds for most values of $n$)?

---

Application:

```
A[n] = x[n] - x[n-1]                 # derivative  (or a smoothed version with moving average)
B[n] = x[n] - 2 * x[n-1] + x[n-2]    # acceleration (idem)
```

I'd like to find when **both** derivative and acceleration of $x[n]$ are positive by studying the sign of **only 1 linear filter**.

*Or said in another way: is it possible to create a linear filter $C[n] = c_0 x[n] + c_1 x[n-1] + ... c_s x[n-s]$ such that $C[n] > 0$ **if and only if** derivative and acceleration of $x[n]$ are both positive?*